# Is there a back / forward functionality in excel, that lets you go back and foward between cells?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to be able to jump back and forth between cells that I've either edited or typed in the `Name Box`.

I've added the forward and backward buttons to the quick access toolbar, but they only work when I click a link.

Comment: Are you open to VBA solutions?

Comment: @EngineerToast Why not?  Sure.

Answer (score 1):

This is an interesting enough idea that I wanted it, too. I would recommend putting the code in your [personal macro workbook](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-and-save-all-your-macros-in-a-single-workbook-66c97ab3-11c2-44db-b021-ae005a9bc790) so it'll work on all your files but you certainly don't have to.

You can use VBA to bind keys to macros. Below is the code to bind <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>NumPad#</kbd> to save cell locations and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>NumPad#</kbd> to activate them. This was inspired by RTS games where you could use CTRL and the number keys to create and select groups of units. Excel already uses CTRL + number row for various shortcuts, though, so I bound them to the number pad instead. It's setup to use the keys 0 - 9 on the numpad so you can save / recall up to 10 ranges. Note that this is a *range* of cells so you can select one, a group, or several disparate cells as you like. I haven't tested what happens if you have multiple *sheets* selected but I doubt it would be very happy with that.

This code goes into the `ThisWorkbook` module. It fires when the workbook is opened thanks to the `Workbook_Open()` event. It'll create a hidden sheet in which to store the saved cells and then creates all the key bindings.

```vb
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    
    ' Create a hidden worksheet to store the saved cells in this workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    On Error Resume Next
    Set ws = Worksheets("SavedCells")
    On Error GoTo 0
    If ws Is Nothing Then
        Set ws = Worksheets.Add
        ws.Name = "SavedCells"
        ws.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
    End If
    
    ' Create key bindings to go to the cells
    Application.OnKey "^{096}", "'gotoCell 0'"  ' CTRL + NumPad0
    Application.OnKey "^{097}", "'gotoCell 1'"  ' CTRL + NumPad1
    Application.OnKey "^{098}", "'gotoCell 2'"  ' CTRL + NumPad2
    Application.OnKey "^{099}", "'gotoCell 3'"  ' CTRL + NumPad3
    Application.OnKey "^{100}", "'gotoCell 4'"  ' CTRL + NumPad4
    Application.OnKey "^{101}", "'gotoCell 5'"  ' CTRL + NumPad5
    Application.OnKey "^{102}", "'gotoCell 6'"  ' CTRL + NumPad6
    Application.OnKey "^{103}", "'gotoCell 7'"  ' CTRL + NumPad7
    Application.OnKey "^{104}", "'gotoCell 8'"  ' CTRL + NumPad8
    Application.OnKey "^{105}", "'gotoCell 9'"  ' CTRL + NumPad9
    
    ' Create key bindings to save the cells
    Application.OnKey "^%{096}", "'saveCell 0'"  ' CTRL + ALT + NumPad0
    Application.OnKey "^%{097}", "'saveCell 1'"  ' CTRL + ALT + NumPad1
    Application.OnKey "^%{098}", "'saveCell 2'"  ' CTRL + ALT + NumPad2
    Application.OnKey "^%{099}", "'saveCell 3'"  ' CTRL + ALT + NumPad3
    Application.OnKey "^%{100}", "'saveCell 4'"  ' CTRL + ALT + NumPad4
    Application.OnKey "^%{101}", "'saveCell 5'"  ' CTRL + ALT + NumPad5
    Application.OnKey "^%{102}", "'saveCell 6'"  ' CTRL + ALT + NumPad6
    Application.OnKey "^%{103}", "'saveCell 7'"  ' CTRL + ALT + NumPad7
    Application.OnKey "^%{104}", "'saveCell 8'"  ' CTRL + ALT + NumPad8
    Application.OnKey "^%{105}", "'saveCell 9'"  ' CTRL + ALT + NumPad9
    
End Sub
```

This codes goes into a module in the same file. It does the work of saving and recalling the cells. For my own purposes, I comment out the message boxes because I wrote the thing so I know what's happening if it doesn't work. You can leave them in or take them out as you please.

```vb
Function gotoCell(cellNumber As Integer)

    ' Convert the cell ID number to a row number
    Dim r As Integer
    r = cellNumber + 1
    
    ' Try to recover the saved cell
    Dim tempRange As Range
    Dim combinedText As String
    On Error Resume Next
        With Worksheets("SavedCells")
            Set tempRange = Workbooks(.Cells(r, 1).Value).Worksheets(.Cells(r, 2).Value).Range(.Cells(r, 3).Value)
            combinedText = .Cells(r, 1) & .Cells(r, 2) & .Cells(r, 3)
        End With
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    ' Go to the cell if it was found
    If Len(combinedText) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Cell " & cellNumber & " has not been saved."
    ElseIf tempRange Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Cell " & cellNumber & " could not be found." & vbNewLine & "It is possible that the workbok was closed or a worksheet was renamed."
    Else
        Application.Goto tempRange
    End If
    
End Function

Function saveCell(cellNumber As Integer)
    
    ' Convert the cell ID number to a row number
    Dim r As Integer
    r = cellNumber + 1
    
    ' Try to get the currently selected cells
    Dim tempRange As Range
    On Error Resume Next
        Set tempRange = Application.Selection
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    ' Save the range if one was found
    If tempRange Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Could not save cell " & cellNumber & "." & vbNewLine & "Please select a cell range and try again."
    Else
        With Worksheets("SavedCells")
            .Cells(r, 1) = tempRange.Parent.Parent.Name
            .Cells(r, 2) = tempRange.Parent.Name
            .Cells(r, 3) = tempRange.Address
        End With
    End If
    
End Function
```

For completeness, you should probably also include this in the `ThisWorkbook` module to *un*bind the keys when you close the workbook. If the code is in your personal macro workbook, this shouldn't matter too much because that typically only closes when you close Excel so the key bindings would be cleared, anyway. However, I still consider it best practice to clean up after yourself.

```vb
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    
    Application.OnKey "^{096}"
    Application.OnKey "^{097}"
    Application.OnKey "^{098}"
    Application.OnKey "^{099}"
    Application.OnKey "^{100}"
    Application.OnKey "^{101}"
    Application.OnKey "^{102}"
    Application.OnKey "^{103}"
    Application.OnKey "^{104}"
    Application.OnKey "^{105}"
    
    Application.OnKey "^%{096}"
    Application.OnKey "^%{097}"
    Application.OnKey "^%{098}"
    Application.OnKey "^%{099}"
    Application.OnKey "^%{100}"
    Application.OnKey "^%{101}"
    Application.OnKey "^%{102}"
    Application.OnKey "^%{103}"
    Application.OnKey "^%{104}"
    Application.OnKey "^%{105}"
    
End Sub
```